# Python just doesn't work at all

Tags: python, crash, python-3.5

For some reason, Python 3.5 just crashes the second I open it up, displaying this:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002168 (most recent call first):
```

When I try to open IDLE, nothing happens.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, repairing, but nothing happens. I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.5. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution mentioned in this answer/comments?

[Python3 installed successfully, but cannot be opened in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946286/python3-installed-successfully-but-cannot-be-opened-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for 3 hours too (I am using Windows 10 as well). Here is the solution:

1. Go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System`, click `Advanced
   system settings` on the left.
2. A window will pop up, hit the tab
   "advanced". Then hit `Environment variables`
3. Scroll down the
   "system variables", double click PYTHONHOME and set it to the
   directory where you have Python installed (for me it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32`).

Hope this helps