# Use Python 3.x on Windows when you can't unset the PYTHONPATH/PYTHONHOME from 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the same problem as is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946286/python3-installed-successfully-but-cannot-be-opened-in-terminal) wherein my Python 3 doesn't work because Python 2 is set in one or more environment variables.

The difference is that I don't have the leeway to change the environment variables. If I do so then one of the old people using the old Python version will throw a temper tantrum, which is a particularly unpleasant sight.

I'd like to be able to set up a Python 3.6 virtual environment on Windows Server 2008 R2. Python 3.6 is installed to a directory but cannot be launched.

[image]

Comment: With Python 3.6.0 comes `py.exe`. Not quite sure if you have to specify the version, so try both `py` and `py -3` in cmd and use whatever works. Does that help?

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin Interesting, but I just tried it and `py.exe` loads 2.7 and `py -3` throws the same error I was getting before when trying to load 3.6

Comment: Consulting [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) might get you somewhere. If you scroll down a little bit, it talks about `py.exe` and `venv`. The latter creates isolated virtual environments for Python.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin Right, I've been trying to create a virtual environment, but I can't. I get the same error when I specify the `--python =` option for a 3.x version.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand the problem (and configuring Python in Windows in general) well enough to help you any further. :( Is there a reason why you don't just use IDLE or Anaconda? Especially Anaconda comes with its own environment `conda` - you just have to be careful not to change the PATH during installation.

Comment: That's OK. I can't use conda because they don't want it on the server. IDLE is there but launching the 3.x version gives the same error.

Comment: Run `set PYTHONHOME=` before running Python. Then run `py -3.6 -m venv P36` to create a 3.6 virtual environment in the P36 directory. Finally, tell whoever is permanently setting `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` that this is an extremely bad and annoying practice.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue I was having where I wanted to create virtual environment(s) with different python versions/builds without needing to remember to $unset PYTHONPATH *every* time I activate a virtual environment. (I am lazy and have a poor memory for such things.)

I added the `unset PYTHONPATH` command to the function workon {} in virtualenvwrapper.sh

On windows, this would entail installing virtualenvwrapper-win and editing the appropriate batch file.

BTW, windows2008 R2 is losing support in July, 2019. And python2.7 is losing support in January, 2020. Since the post is two years old, I assume you've updated the OS and python on the server. If not prepare yourself for the impending tantrum.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you described.

Like the previous answer, you could manually `set PYTHONHOME=` which deletes the environment variable temporarily and run the installer from the CMD/Powershell terminal. 
This works, but its not very convinient.

A better solution is to add a user environment variable `PYTHONHOME` with a value of an empty string. In Windows 7, this can't be done in the GUI. Instead, use

`setx PYTHONHOME ""`

in the command prompt.

This will override the system variable with the same name. Now you can install any Anaconda distribution you like.