# python stopped working on anaconda prompt startup

Tags: python, anaconda

Recently i have installed anaconda 64 bit python 3 version on my laptop.
when i started anaconda prompt, it shows error of "Python has stopped working"

This is error in prompt,

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
raise CodecRegistryError,\

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have done enough search but couldn't find anything.
Please help me resolve this error.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the rid of error. 
Since i had python 2.7 installed and was trying to install anaconda with python 3.

I had to uninstall python 2.7, now it works fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to usually be because the pythonhome environment variable is not set.

See the first comment on the answer in this stack overflow post
[Python3 installed successfully, but cannot be opened in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946286/python3-installed-successfully-but-cannot-be-opened-in-terminal)

Comment: I did enter correct path in all environment variable. Still the error is persistent.