# Python crashes when running Azure CLI 2.0

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-cli2

I installed Azure CLI 2.0 for windows (with the .msi installation).
Then I opened powershell and typed `az` and I saw the CLI welcome screen but also I got a windows error window saying that `"Python has stopped working"`.
so everytime I try to lunch azure cli 2.0 I get this python stopped working window.

I'm using python and pycharm regardless and everything works great.

Anyone have a clue how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could uninstall and reinstall it, but depending on the error you are getting, the problem might persist. "Python stopped working" is a rather generic error that can have a number of causes, but it [is commenly caused by multiple Python environments and/or the pythonhome environment variable not having been set.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526539/python-stopped-working-on-anaconda-prompt-startup/43544953)

You can also try launching the az command from bash, (start program -> cmd and then use the az command from the C:> prompt.

If that doesn't work, There are a few workarounds:

**Install on Windows subsystem for Linux**

If you're on Windows 10, you could try installing the Azure CLI and on Ubuntu Bash.

Enabling Ubuntu Bash is described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/):

- Settings -> Update and Security -> For Developers -> Developer Mode
- Control Panel -> Programs -> Windows Features -> Windows Subsystem for Linux

Installing the Azure CLI here is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#install-with-apt-get-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows):

**Use Powershell**

You're launching the Azure CLI from Powershell, but there is really no need to do this: The Powershell Azure tooling is just as good if not better. For example, if you wanted to resize a virtual disk, you could use the [Update-AzureRmVm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk) command.

**Use CLI from the browser**

Nowadays you can start a Azure CLI command prompt directly from the portal, using the button with >_ in the upper right corner. Upside: you can access this command prompt from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The same happens when I use the command prompt (python crashes). I tried re-installing the CLI but the problem remains the same. I will try to use the azure powershell tool but Im not sure it supports what I need which is to expand one of my linux vms disk. I will also try the "windows subsystem for linux" as it sounds cool. Thank again.

Comment: What error is python reporting? The procedure for expanding an OS drive in an azure VM using Powershell is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk

Comment: The "python stopped working" message was addressed here" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526539/python-stopped-working-on-anaconda-prompt-startup/43544953